# What is wrong with the output of this attempt at dynamically resizing an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic, null

I am trying to resize an array dynamically in C++ and am going through the steps, but the output is not matching up with the numbers I am putting into the array. First, I create a new array with a larger size, then I copy over all the elements of the original array, then I add another element to the new array, delete the old array, and set the pointer of the old array to the new array.

I'm not sure if I should return the pointer, because the parameter is passed by reference, right?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void resize( int*, int, int );

int main()
{
        int *arr = new int[5];
        for( int i=0; i<5; i++ )
                arr[i] = i;
        for( int i=0; i<5; i++ )
                cout << arr[i];
        cout << endl;


        resize( arr, 5, 5 );
        for( int i=0; i<6; i++ )
                cout << arr[i] << endl;
        cout << endl;
        return 0;
}


void resize( int *arr, int size, int yes )
{
        int *newA = new int[size+1];
        for( int i=0; i<size; i++ )
        {
                cout << arr[i];
                newA[i] = arr[i];
        }
        delete [] arr;
        newA[size] = yes;
        arr = newA;
}
```

This is the output:

002340

but I want the new array to be 0 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: `arr` is a pointer, but it is passed by value to `resize()`.   So assignment of `arr = newA` is not visible to the caller.   One option to correct this pass a pointer to a pointer `int **arr` as argument, change usage `arr[i]` to `(*arr)[i]`, and change `delete [] arr; arr = newA` to `delete *arr; *arr = newA` in the function to `(*arr)`.  `main()` will then need to pass `&arr`.     A second choice is to change the first argument of `resize()` to be a reference to a pointer  i.e. `int *& arr` in which case no other changes are needed.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `arr` value as a pointer, not by reference. We can modify `resize` to pass the pointer by reference just by adding `&`:

```
// Passes the pointer to 'arr' by reference
void resize(int*& arr, int size, int yes )
{
        int *newA = new int[size+1];
        for( int i=0; i<size; i++ )
        {
                cout << arr[i];
                newA[i] = arr[i];
        }
        delete [] arr;
        newA[size] = yes;
        arr = newA;
}
```

That being said, the standard library has a built-in class that already does this! It's called `std::vector`, and it's well-built, just as fast as a regular array (when you compile with optimizations), and it automatically deletes whatever memory it allocates!

With `std::vector`, the original code looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> arr(5); // Create a vector with 5 elements

    // Assign them
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++ )
        arr[i] = i;
    // Print them
    for( int i=0; i<5; i++ )
        cout << arr[i];
    cout << endl;

    // add the number 5 at the end of arr
    // resize happens automatically
    arr.push_back(5); 

    // The number 5 now appears at the end of the array
    for( int i=0; i<6; i++ )
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```